# How to put date range in Apex to make checkbox field true or false?

Tags: apex

If the `ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c` field is equal to Today or it must be within 3 future days from today then only urgency flag TRUE.

let say today date is 9/1/2024 and for next 3 days also flag must be true.
9/1/2024
10/1/2024
11/1/2024
12/1/2024 for these days flag must be TRUE.

This field is a data type of date and time in system.

### Apex class

```
  public static void updateUrgencyFlag(Map<Id,Case> newCaseMap,Map<Id,Case> oldCaseMap){
    system.debug('start---->');
    for(Case caseRec: newCaseMap.values()){
        system.debug('start 1---->');
        
        if(caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c  <= System.today()+3){
            caseRec.ET_Urgency_flag__c = TRUE;
            
        }else{
            caseRec.ET_Urgency_flag__c = FALSE;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a formula field here? If you expect the field to change value as the days go by you would have a lot less trouble if it were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. To add days to a date in Apex, you need to use the `addDays` method:

```
 if(caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c <= System.today().addDays(3))
```

Be aware that this will catch any dates that are earlier than the current date too. If you want to exclude those, add another condition:

```
if(caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c <= System.today().addDays(3) && caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c >= System.today())
```

Comment: thank you so much bro logic works fine now